# Cannot resolve symbol 'appcompat'

Tags: android

I'm trying to import this 3 libraries: ActivityCompat, AppCompatActivity, ContextCompat
and turn into errors like: Cannot resolve symbol 'appcompat' and Cannot resolve symbol 'core'. I tried: Clean Project and Invalidate Caches.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.limeparallelogram.imgtransmitproject"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

androidx.appcompat.app.ActivityCompat doesn't auto-complete on my Android Studio. Try:

```
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
```

Comment: It doesn't work..